# regex - How to find and replace one variable with multiple random variables?

Tags: regex, variables, replace, find

I have a list of URLs all from the same domain. Example :

domain1.com/urlA

domain1.com/urlB

domain1.com/urlC

domain1.com/urlD
................

i want to replace domain1 with multiple random domains (domain2,domain3, etc) 
the results should be something like :

domain2.com/urlA

domain3.com/urlB

domain4.com/urlC

domain2.com/urlD

...............

I'm totally a newbie to regex. I searched 2 hours on the internet and couldn't find a solution to this!

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question.With your stated trail code and error... people are more willing to help you so both can learn. In addition, add your programming language too.. regex is broadly used ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what language you're using for this problem, but if you must use regexes, the npm package [randexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/randexp) looks like a good and clean solution. This package contains functions that generate a random string matching some Regular Expression Javascript object.

So, you can use some string manipulation functions to replace "domain1" with the strings generated by `randexp` like this:

```js
var RandExp = require('randexp');

// returns a String of the format "domain" then a random digit 0-9 at the back
// e.g. "domain0", "domain1"..., "domain9"
console.log(new RandExp(/domain\d/).gen())
```

If not, I suggest just removing the string `"domain1"` from the first part of the URL and replacing that with the word `"domain"` concatenated with a randomly generated digit.